# Linq + Where + abstract method = LINQ to Entities does not recognize method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

First of all: I know that there were already many questions before about this topic. But I really could not find any solutions mor MY problem. My problem is that I am using an abstract method to select from an dbset. My code looks like this:

```
var dbe = (from i in dbEntities where IsEqualRecord(me, i) select i);
```

And this is my abstract method deklaration:

```
protected abstract bool IsEqualRecord(MEntity modelEntities, DEntity databaseEntity);
```

`MEntity` and `DEntity` are generic-types. I've read that my where Statement can't be translated to an sql statement. But how can I solve that problem? Is there any other approach?

Please don't vote to close this question. I've took a look at nearly every similar question on stackoverflow but I could not find a solution.

Comment: You can't use custom method in a `LINQ to SQL` or `LINQ to Entity` query.

Comment: I don't think the method being abstract has anything to do to it... only `Expression<>` objects can be used in Linq to SQL IIRC.  (Lambdas are convertible to `Expression<>`; method groups are not.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq to Entities queries are translated to SQL to be executed by the DBMS, so you can only use code that can be translated to SQL. A custom C# method cannot be translated to SQL, so EF fails to translate the query. The fact that it's abstract is irrelevant.

A possible workaround would be to replace `IsEqualRecord` by a method that returns an `Expression<Func<DEntity, bool>>` that can be translated to SQL; you could then do something like that:

```
var dbe = dbEntities.Where(MakeEqualityPredicate(me));

...


protected abstract Expression<Func<DEntity, bool>> MakeEqualityPredicate(MEntity m);
```

The `MakeEqualityPredicate` method should return an Expression that compares a `DEntity` to the given `MEntity`. For instance, a derived class could implement it like this:

```
protected override Expression<Func<DEntity, bool>> MakeEqualityPredicate(MEntity m)
{
    return d => d.Id == m.Id;
}
```

Comment: @cdhowie, actually I think your answer explained it better, so you could undelete it...