# Entity Framework throws NotSupportedException after calling Any or Count

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've got the following code:

```
private void Import(DbSet<DBEntity> dbEntities, IEnumerable<ExcelEntity> entities, ClapEntities context)
{
    foreach (var me in entities)
    {
        try
        {
            var dbe = dbEntities.Where(IsEqualRecord(me, context));
            bool hasElement = dbe.Any(); //Line which throws the exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

protected abstract Expression<Func<DBEntity, bool>> IsEqualRecord(ExcelEntity entity, ClapEntities context);
```

The `Any()` extension throws a `NotSupportedException`:

> System.Exception: Could not map entity to database. Mapper: [CuttingToolImport]; Rownumber: [153] ---> System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.FirstTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, DbExpression operand, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.AggregateTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_a()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_9()
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1  operation)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>
>   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
>   at CLAP.Models.Import.ImportMapping.ImportBase`2.Import(DbSet`1 dbEntities, IEnumerable`1 entities, ClapEntities context)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

As you can see, the `Any()` extension (or the `Count()` extension) uses the `First()` extension internal which is not allowed. I have no idea how I can fix that error.

Exactly this code has worked for many months with Entity Framework version 5 or 6 and

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) Express Edition (64-bit) on
Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve that error?

Comment: It may be an issue with `IsEqualRecord` method which may not be able to be translated to sql.

Comment: Well. But I did not change anything on the whole code for month. And it worked at any time.

Comment: What was the change that broke the behavior?

Comment: Of course that's weird, but it must be in your `IsEqualRecord` method, because `Any` as such always works. `IsEqualRecord` is executed when `Any` is called.

Comment: Can you show the source of `IsEqualRecord`?

Comment: I will try out your advice @GertArnold

Comment: Ok. You were right. But I still don't understand why this error occurs  after a few month without any changes. Anyway. The IsEqualRecord-method contained a First() instruction.

Comment: Maybe you had data that for the first time hit the execution path with `First`.

Comment: I'm afraid thats not possible. I am using exactly the same import file since month... but anyway. It works :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead which will return `NULL` when there is no entities in dataset:

```
bool hasElement = dbe.FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

Another *possible* issue in your code is that you're using custom `IsEqualRecord` method which should contain **only** code that can be translated into *SQL*.

Comment: First of all, I can not modify code inside the EntityFramework. I do not call First(). I call Any() or Count() WHICH CALLS First(). And the next thing is that the IsEqualRecord function can be translated into SQL. It gets translated into SQL for many month now. It got solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283307/linq-where-abstract-method-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-method

Comment: @thefiloe Ok, maybe I was not clear. Instead of `.Any()` use `.FirstOrDefault() != null`.

Comment: I think `dbe.FirstOrDefault()` will throw the same exception. Would be interesting to see that confirmed because that would really pin it down to `IsEqualRecord`.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just came across it.. I fixed my incident by adding .toList() before .any().. Hoping this helps someone in the future. dbContext.MyCoolTable.ToList().Any()

Comment: @Timothy You're right cuz after invoking `.ToList()` you'll be using _Linq to Objects_ instead _Linq to Entities_. **BUT** you shouldn't do this. Huge drawback of such approach is that you'll load all dataset into memory and then filter out needed items which is _inefficient_ from multiple perspectives (memory utilization, performance).